# Select with CSS the last div in recursive div layout

Tags: css, recursion, css-selectors

With the below HTML, **how i can select the DIV depper (which has no children)?**

I think that i can use nth-last-child but dont work because all divs has the last (and also the first)! :D

PD: Not is possible the use of the ID or CLASS property in the DIV deeper (because they are HTML existent files in web)

**Html:**

```
<div class="base">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <!-- recursive divs (quantity not defined...) -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

CSS selectors cannot look to the parent elements, sadly, so you can't see which elements don't have `div`s as children.

If you are using jQuery, you can do this to find the element:

```
$('.base :not(:has(*))').addClass('deepest');​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EhZax/

Comment: Way *way* **way** ***way*** faster: http://jsperf.com/jquery-filter-vs-complex-selector

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use Javascript. Here's an example using jQuery:

```
$('.base *').filter(function(){
    return ! $(this).find('> *').length;
});
```

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/E6sec/

---

**Update:** If you want to, you could create your own `:sterile` selector. Here's an example:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].sterile = function(el) {
    return ! el.children.length;
};
```

You could then just use it as you would any other pseudo selector:

```
$('.base :sterile');​
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FBw5q/

**P.S.** I used the native `el.children` since [it's way faster than any of jQuery's methods](http://jsperf.com/node-children-vs-this-find-vs-this-children). However, IE < 9 will include comments as `children`. If that concerns you, you can use jQuery's `children()` method.

Comment: I think you can condense it a little more to `$('.base *').filter(function() { return $(this).children().length == 0; });`.

Comment: @Blender - Thanks. Updated. Strangely, `find('> *')` is faster than `children()`.

Comment: @Blender - Interesting. Chrome and Opera have better performance with `find`, while IE, Firefox & Safari are better off with `children`. Weird.

Comment: Interesting aplication of JQuery @JosephSilber, Blender.

Comment: @Blender In CSS4 (or maybe 5?) should be a selector pseudo-class as **:sterile** or something similar no?. How do we suggest this?

Comment: @lcoronelp - CSS3 has the `:empty` selector, which selects empty elements. This is not what you want here. `:empty` only selects elements that are completely empty. If there's any text (or even a comment) in them, they won't be selected.

Comment: @JosephSilber yes, the `:empty` selector would not work, i think that the **:sterile** proposed selector should select only DOM elements that have no other HTML elements internally. For example i like select only the `p` without others elements inside. I it see functional no?

Comment: @lcoronelp - I added a custom jQuery filter expression, so that you could use `:sterile` the way you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

You need Javascript for that. It's not possible with CSS only